# context createAudioBuffer is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I want to use this codepen highcharts vu meter with mic input using getusermedia api for my apps, but never succeed to get in done : https://codepen.io/slatius/pen/BqblG?editors=1111

`var buffer = context.createAudioBuffer(11025,100,0.2);`

i'm not too good in javascript and runs out idea to fix it. it keeps throwing out this error when run :

`Uncaught TypeError: context.createAudioBuffer is not a function`

Maybe someone kind enough to help me solve this please?

Comment: It's called [`createBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createBuffer)

Comment: Thank you kaiido for the help. appreciate this. according to the BaseAudioContext, i've change to this :
```var buffer = context.createBuffer(2, 22050, 44100);```
and the error now is gone. 
However, the vumeter still not moving when i talk to the mic.

Comment: That's for an other question, where you will show a [mcve] in the question itself.